# JQuery add options to select dynamically for 7 different selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page which has 14 different selects, each select is for a day of the week (i.e. Monday - Sunday), each day has 2 selects, one for opening time and one for closing time. I populate all 14 selects with a list in JQuery, here is my full code below:

```
//hours to populate select
var arr_hours = [
    {val: '00:00:00', text: '00:00'},
    {val: '00:30:00', text: '00:30'},
    {val: '01:00:00', text: '01:00'},
    {val: '01:30:00', text: '01:30'},
    {val: '02:00:00', text: '02:00'},
    {val: '02:30:00', text: '02:30'},
    {val: '03:00:00', text: '03:00'},
    {val: '03:30:00', text: '03:30'},
    {val: '04:00:00', text: '04:00'},
    {val: '04:30:00', text: '04:30'},
    {val: '05:00:00', text: '05:00'},
    {val: '05:30:00', text: '05:30'},
    {val: '06:00:00', text: '06:00'},
    {val: '06:30:00', text: '06:30'},
    {val: '07:00:00', text: '07:00'},
    {val: '07:30:00', text: '07:30'},
    {val: '08:00:00', text: '08:00'},
    {val: '08:30:00', text: '08:30'},
    {val: '09:00:00', text: '09:00'},
    {val: '09:30:00', text: '09:30'},
    {val: '10:00:00', text: '10:00'},
    {val: '10:30:00', text: '10:30'},
    {val: '11:00:00', text: '11:00'},
    {val: '11:30:00', text: '11:30'},
    {val: '12:00:00', text: '12:00'},
    {val: '12:30:00', text: '12:30'},
    {val: '13:00:00', text: '13:00'},
    {val: '13:30:00', text: '13:30'},
    {val: '14:00:00', text: '14:00'},
    {val: '14:30:00', text: '14:30'},
    {val: '15:00:00', text: '15:00'},
    {val: '15:30:00', text: '15:30'},
    {val: '16:00:00', text: '16:00'},
    {val: '16:30:00', text: '16:30'},
    {val: '17:00:00', text: '17:00'},
    {val: '17:30:00', text: '17:30'},
    {val: '18:00:00', text: '18:00'},
    {val: '18:30:00', text: '18:30'},
    {val: '19:00:00', text: '19:00'},
    {val: '19:30:00', text: '19:30'},
    {val: '20:00:00', text: '20:00'},
    {val: '20:30:00', text: '20:30'},
    {val: '21:00:00', text: '21:00'},
    {val: '21:30:00', text: '21:30'},
    {val: '22:00:00', text: '22:00'},
    {val: '22:30:00', text: '22:30'},
    {val: '23:00:00', text: '23:00'},
    {val: '23:30:00', text: '23:30'},
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Add time values to business hours selects
    add_hours();
});

//populate all selects from the array
function add_hours(){
    //monday
    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#mon_open_from").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#mon_open_from option[value="08:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected');

    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#mon_open_to").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#mon_open_to option[value="17:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected'); 
    // /monday

    //tuesday
    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#tue_open_from").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#tue_open_from option[value="08:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected');

    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#tue_open_to").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#tue_open_to option[value="17:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected'); 
    // /tuesday

    //wednesday
    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#wed_open_from").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#wed_open_from option[value="08:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected');

    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#wed_open_to").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#wed_open_to option[value="17:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected'); 
    // /wednesday

    //thursday
    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#thur_open_from").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#thur_open_from option[value="08:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected');

    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#thur_open_to").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#thur_open_to option[value="17:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected');    
    // /thursday

    //friday
    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#fri_open_from").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#fri_open_from option[value="08:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected');

    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#fri_open_to").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#fri_open_to option[value="17:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected'); 
    // /friday

    //saturday
    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#sat_open_from").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#sat option[value="08:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected');

    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#sat_open_to").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#sat_open_to option[value="17:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected'); 
    // /monday

    //sunday
    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#sun_open_from").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#sun_open_from option[value="08:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected');

    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("#sun_open_to").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $('#sun_open_to option[value="17:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected'); 
    // /monday

}
```

The code above works, but it is very repetitive and feels chunky. How can I improve the code?

Comment: run a loop for days as well. save ids in an array may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace add_hours() to be as below:

```js
function add_hours(){
    
    $(arr_hours).each(function() {
        $("select[id$='_open_from']").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
        $("select[id$='_open_to']").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });

    $("select[id$='_open_from'] option[value='08:00:00']").attr('selected','selected');
    $("select[id$='_open_to'] option[value='17:00:00']").attr('selected','selected');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The technique you're looking for is called DRY, for Don't Repeat Yourself. The easiest way to do this in this case is to use common classes to group elements by behaviour. For example, add classes to differentiate `select` which are for opening times, and which are for closing. Then you can target them all in one go.

You can then build a single array of `option` element HTML from the original array and use it to set the HTML of all the `select` in one call to `html()`.

Finally you can call `val()` on the relevant classes to set the times. There is no need for any explicit loops. Try this:

```js
//hours to populate select
var arr_hours = [{val:"00:00:00",text:"00:00"},{val:"00:30:00",text:"00:30"},{val:"01:00:00",text:"01:00"},{val:"01:30:00",text:"01:30"},{val:"02:00:00",text:"02:00"},{val:"02:30:00",text:"02:30"},{val:"03:00:00",text:"03:00"},{val:"03:30:00",text:"03:30"},{val:"04:00:00",text:"04:00"},{val:"04:30:00",text:"04:30"},{val:"05:00:00",text:"05:00"},{val:"05:30:00",text:"05:30"},{val:"06:00:00",text:"06:00"},{val:"06:30:00",text:"06:30"},{val:"07:00:00",text:"07:00"},{val:"07:30:00",text:"07:30"},{val:"08:00:00",text:"08:00"},{val:"08:30:00",text:"08:30"},{val:"09:00:00",text:"09:00"},{val:"09:30:00",text:"09:30"},{val:"10:00:00",text:"10:00"},{val:"10:30:00",text:"10:30"},{val:"11:00:00",text:"11:00"},{val:"11:30:00",text:"11:30"},{val:"12:00:00",text:"12:00"},{val:"12:30:00",text:"12:30"},{val:"13:00:00",text:"13:00"},{val:"13:30:00",text:"13:30"},{val:"14:00:00",text:"14:00"},{val:"14:30:00",text:"14:30"},{val:"15:00:00",text:"15:00"},{val:"15:30:00",text:"15:30"},{val:"16:00:00",text:"16:00"},{val:"16:30:00",text:"16:30"},{val:"17:00:00",text:"17:00"},{val:"17:30:00",text:"17:30"},{val:"18:00:00",text:"18:00"},{val:"18:30:00",text:"18:30"},{val:"19:00:00",text:"19:00"},{val:"19:30:00",text:"19:30"},{val:"20:00:00",text:"20:00"},{val:"20:30:00",text:"20:30"},{val:"21:00:00",text:"21:00"},{val:"21:30:00",text:"21:30"},{val:"22:00:00",text:"22:00"},{val:"22:30:00",text:"22:30"},{val:"23:00:00",text:"23:00"},{val:"23:30:00",text:"23:30"}];

jQuery(function($) {
  add_hours();
});

//populate all selects from the array
function add_hours() {
  var html = arr_hours.map(item => `<option value="${item.val}">${item.text}</option>`);
  let $selects = $('.day-select').html(html);
  $selects.filter('.open').val('08:00:00');
  $selects.filter('.close').val('17:00:00');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Monday</p>
  <label>Open: <select name="mon-open" class="day-select open"></select></label>
  <label>Close: <select name="mon-close" class="day-select close"></select></label>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Tuesday</p>
  <label>Open: <select name="tue-open" class="day-select open"></select></label>
  <label>Close: <select name="tue-close" class="day-select close"></select></label>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Wednesday</p>
  <label>Open: <select name="wed-open" class="day-select open"></select></label>
  <label>Close: <select name="wed-close" class="day-select close"></select></label>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Thursday</p>
  <label>Open: <select name="thu-open" class="day-select open"></select></label>
  <label>Close: <select name="thu-close" class="day-select close"></select></label>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Friday</p>
  <label>Open: <select name="fri-open" class="day-select open"></select></label>
  <label>Close: <select name="fri-close" class="day-select close"></select></label>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Saturday</p>
  <label>Open: <select name="sat-open" class="day-select open"></select></label>
  <label>Close: <select name="sat-close" class="day-select close"></select></label>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Sunday</p>
  <label>Open: <select name="sun-open" class="day-select open"></select></label>
  <label>Close: <select name="sun-close" class="day-select close"></select></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Rory's answer , you can also poulate arr_hours like so :

```js
var arr_hours = [];
for(i=0;i<23;i++){
if(i<10){
arr_hours.push({val:'0'+i.toString()+':00'+':00',text:'0'+i.toString()+':00'});
arr_hours.push({val:'0'+i.toString()+':30'+':00',text:'0'+i.toString()+':30'});
               }
 
else
{
arr_hours.push({val:i.toString()+':00'+':00',text:i.toString()+':00'});
arr_hours.push({val:i.toString()+':30'+':00',text:i.toString()+':30'});
}
}
console.log(arr_hours)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add class name in your html file for all select. Like,

```
<select name="sun_open_to" id="sun_open_to" class="all close"></select>
<select name="sun_open_from" id="sun_open_from" class="all open"></select>
```

Write code for class name. Like,

```
  $(arr_hours).each(function() {
    $(".all").append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
  });
  $('.open option[value="08:00:00"]').attr('selected','
  $('.close option[value="17:00:00"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

It works in my codepen: 
https://codepen.io/hiral13/pen/NWPgPPQ